# Why is my sed command not calling out my variable c?

Tags: bash, for-loop, sed

Good afternoon here is my bash code:

```
for f in {-20..20};
do
     cd V_$f;
     echo V_$f;
     c= echo "$f /10" | bc -l | xargs printf "%.1f";
     echo $c;
     sed -i -e "s/TS.Voltage 0.0 eV/TS.Voltage "$c" eV/" scattering.fdf;
     cd ..;
done;
```

When called under the name V.sh, the outcome is for example

```
V_-20
-2.0
...
```

and so on till `V_20` / `2.0` representing my folder and the value `c` needed in each file. My question is when I look up at my fdf file in each of my folders to see if the command `sed` is working, the value of `c` is not shown. In fact i get `TS.Voltage "space"  eV` instead of the value of `c`. Any advice please?

Comment: Perhaps you need `$()` or backticks around the expression to which `c` is assigned.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "Here's a bunch of my code, please debug it for me" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask] for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
c= echo "$f /10" | bc -l | xargs printf "%.1f";
```

Reads as "Set `c` to empty temporarily, then run the `echo`/`bc`/`xargs` pipeline". To store the result of a program or programs in a variable, use `$(...)`:

```
c=$(echo "$f /10" | bc -l | xargs printf "%.1f")
```

Next, you may want to fix your `sed` expression:

- The whole point of double quotes is that environment variables *do* get expanded in them.
- Dot matches any single character. You need to escape it to match a literal period.

The command should look like this:

```
"s/TS\.Voltage 0\.0 eV/TS.Voltage $c eV/"
```

You really don't need a semicolon at the end of each line, although I suppose it can't hurt.

Comment: Thank you very much!  You are right $(...) did the trick. I did not even need to change TS line.